# Can a triangle free graph represent a Group?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, group-isomorphism, algebraic-graph-theory

Some facts are-

1. Group can be represented by a graph.
2. Group Isomorphism $\leq_p$ Graph Isomorphism.

Under this context, my questions is-

1. Can a triangle free graph represent a group?

Edit: 
 My motivation is to see the interaction between group isomorphism and  graph isomorphism,so
 please consider groups that can be represented by simple graphs but not trees as tree isomorphism can be solved in log time.

**In general, consider hard instances of groups  for group isomorphism which are represented by graphs that are also hard graph isomorphism instances.**

Comment: When you say "groups can be represented by a graph" do you mean the Cayley graph ?

Comment: @CaptainLama yes, caley graphs are directed but even if  you don't keep the direction of caley graph , they still represent a group.

Comment: Then free groups are "represented" by trees.

Comment: @CaptainLama   thats ok but can there be a triangle free graph that  represents a group but the graph is not a tree?

Comment: Like... the Cayley graph for a cyclic group with $n \neq 3$ elements?

Comment: At any rate, if you just wants lots of examples of (gorgeous) Cayley graphs, check out [weddslist](http://www.weddslist.com/groups/cayley-plat/index.html). You can spot a few different Cayley graphs for a variety of groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the Cayley graph is not canonical : for a given group $G$, each choice of a generating set will give a different Cayley graph.

And every group with at least $3$ elements has a Cayley graph with triangles : if $x\neq y$ in $G$, put $x$, $y$ and $xy^{-1}$ in the generating set, and this will give you a triangle in the Cayley graph.

On the other hand, unless your generating set has elements of order $3$, you can always remove the triangles by changing the generating set. Indeed, if there is a triangle, then by homogeneity you canfind one with one of the vertices labeled by the neutral element. Then (assuming the generating set $S$ is symmetric) the other two vertices are labeled with $x,y\in S$ and the edges are labeled with $x$, $y$ and $z\in S$. The fact that it's a triangle then means that $z=yx^{-1}$ or $z=yx^{-1}$. Then analysing all cases ($z=x^{\pm 1}$, $z=y^{\pm 1}$, $z\neq x^{\pm 1},y^{\pm 1}$) shows that you can remove one of those generators, thus removing the triangle.

Comment: I  think your last statement is correct, but it is not obvious and a proof requires some work.  For example, it is not true if you replace $3$ by $4$. If you take an abelian group of rank at least 2, then, for any generating set, the corresponding Cayley graph will have $4$-cycles, (even if the group has no element of order $4$).

Comment: You're right, I added a short proof.

Comment: That proof is incorrect. For example, on the surface, that proofs work for 4 as well, but the conclusion is wrong in this case. The problem is that the 3- or 4-cycle might have repeated elements. In your notation, we might have $x=z$ so that removing $z$ removes $x$ and we might no longer have a generating set. In the 3-cycle case, that can actually be avoided, with some care...

Comment: Ah, that's not what I would call a triangle, then. I guess it's a matter of definitions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use the same labels as you did. I mean that two of the three edge labels are equal.

Comment: Ah yes I see your point, indeed you have to treat separately the case $z=x$ and $z=y$, but in each case you can remove one of them.

Comment: Exactly. It's not hard, but it's an important subtlety, and it only works for 3-cycles, not 4-cycles or longer ones.

Comment: @CaptainLama , To summarize: since Cayley graph is not canonical,  we can always construct a Non-Triangle-Free graph for any given group (group are given in table/2D matrix), right?

Comment: Yes, you can always find a Cayley graph with triangles for your group if it has at least $3$ elements.